# TinyMCE customization

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I want to design an editor, but don't want to use TinyMCE's tool bar.

I need the ability for the user ton apply styles to the selected element or its selected content using my own interface, so that I can handle the styles using jQuery.

However, none of TinyMCE's toolbar will be used. Can I handle styles in such a way? Will it be stable and cross browser compatible ? What will be the best solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is possible cause you are able to get the editors selection from outside the editor (which you need to apply styles to). Some prerequisitions are:

- the styles should be in your custom.css
- in case you want to trigger actions depending on the editor you will need to write an own plugin